# Integration problem that may use DCT

Tags: real-analysis, integration, limits

I am trying to solve the following problem.

Let $f \in L^2(0,1)$ and define

$$f_n(x)= n \int\limits_{k/n}^{(k+1)/n} f(y) dy $$

for $x \in [k/n, (k+1)/n)$, $k=0,1, \dots, n-1.$

Show that $f_n \rightarrow f$ in $L^1.$

Intuitively I know that the integral part is approaching $f(x).$  I am not sure how to make this precise.  I would appreciate any hints.  Thank you!

Comment: May you use http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lebesgue_differentiation_theorem?, or are you supposed to prove it?

Comment: To show convergence in L^1 and apply Lebesgue differentiation we need to be able to pull the limit inside.  I don't think we are allowed to use Lebesgue differentiation.  This was a homework problem in the Fall that I am now trying to figure out.

Answer (score 0):

First suppose $f$ is a continuous function on $[0,1)$ with compact support. Then $f$ is uniformly continuous, so given $\varepsilon > 0$, there corresponds a $\delta > 0$ such that for all $x$ and $y$, $|x - y| < \delta$ implies $|f(x) - f(y)| < \varepsilon$. Let $N$ be a positive integer such that $\frac{1}{N} < \delta$. If $n \ge N$, then for $k = 0,1,\ldots, n-1$, $$\int_{k/n}^{(k+1)/n}|f_n(x) - f(x)| \le \int_{k/n}^{(k+1)/n} n\int_{k/n}^{(k+1)/n} |f(y) - f(x)|\, dy\, dx <  \int_{k/n}^{(k+1)/n}\varepsilon\, dx = \frac{\varepsilon}{n}.$$ Hence $\|f_n - f\|_1 < \varepsilon$ for all $n \ge N$. This shows that $f_n \xrightarrow{L^1} f$.

Now suppose $f \in L^2(0,1)$. Let $\varepsilon > 0$. Choose $g \in C_c([0,1))$ such that $\|f - g\|_\infty < \frac{\varepsilon}{3}$. Then $\|f - g\|_1 \le \|f - g\|_\infty < \frac{\varepsilon}{3}$. Furthermore, for $n \in \Bbb N$ and $k = 0,1,\ldots, n-1$, $$\int_{k/n}^{(k+1)/n} |f_n(x) - g_n(x)|\, dx \le \int_{k/n}^{(k+1)/n} \int_{k/n}^{(k+1)/n} n\|f - g\|_\infty\,dy\, dx < \frac{\varepsilon}{3n}.$$ Therefore $\|f_n - g_n\|_\infty < \frac{\varepsilon}{3}$ for all $n \in \Bbb N$. Since $g_n \xrightarrow{L^1} g$, there exists an $N \in \Bbb N$ such that $\|g_n - g\|_1 < \frac{\varepsilon}{3}$ for all $n \ge N$. So if $n \ge N$, $$\|f_n - f\|_1 \le \|f_n - g_n\|_1 + \|g_n - g\|_1 + \|g - f\|_1 < \frac{\varepsilon}{3} + \frac{\varepsilon}{3} + \frac{\varepsilon}{3} = \varepsilon.$$ Since $\varepsilon$ is arbitrary, $f_n \xrightarrow{L^1} f$.